# AWS-SDK-S3 InvalidArgument: Unsupported Accept-Encoding specified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3

estoy intentado integrar aws-s3 de amazon a mi proyecto de ruby on rails + active_storage, ya hice todo lo correcto para que la instalacion no de problemas, pero a la hora de hacer un upload a mi bucket me lanza este error:
Completed 500 Internal Server Error
Aws::S3::Errors::InvalidArgument(Unsupported Accept-Encoding specified).

Sabiendo que mi proyecto es muy grande, hice tan solo un script y me lanza exactamente el mismo error. La version del aws-sdk-s3 es v1 y mi version de ruby es 2.4.2. Estoy hace semanas con esto y no puedo encontrar la solucion. Gracias!

El script es el siguiente:

```
require "rubygems"
require "aws-sdk-v1"
require "zlib"
require "base64"

s3 = AWS::S3.new(
 :acces_key_id => "...",
 :secret_access_key => "...",
 :region => "us-east-2",
 :s3_endpoint => "...")
bucketX = s3.buckets[my-bucket]

file = File.open("imagen.jpeg", "rb")
file64 = Base64.encode64(File.open("imagen.jpeg", "rb").read)
stringX = "asd"
obj = bucketX.objects["key"].write(stringX)
```

Posdata: En este ejemplo pruebo mandando el stringX, probe de varias formas, tanto mandando al imagen cruda, en png, jpeg,etc y tambien mandando Base64.

Comment: Hola Juan, bienvenido a SOes. Revisa [ask] para saber que se necesita en una pregunta de esta comunidad. Por lo pronto, no hay forma de saber la causa de tu error si no compartes el código que genera dicho error. Saludos

Comment: @AlterLagos, gracias por avisar, ahi ya lo edite!